# LookupOrderedRows not working in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, query, dataextensions

I have a microsite in which I am using this:

```
SET @DEName = "My_DataExtensionName"
SET @DELookup = LookupOrderedRows(@DEName,1000000,desc,"Statue","true") 
SET @CountDELookup = RowCount(@DELookup)
```

Displaying it in microsite like this:

%%=v(@CountDELookup)=%%

But, why same is not working when I use this ampscript in email?

It seems like 1000000, desc is causing an issue. When I remove these fields and use simple LookupRows(), I get the results.

**A few points:**

- My output number is a lot more than 2000 which is why I am using LookupOrderedRows
- desc is not a column in my data extension but it is working in my microsite

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need an exact to the moment count, you could just have it be a filtered DE based on 'Status = true' and then run that filter in an automation (at your preferred interval) and then in the emails do a [DataExensionRowCount()](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/dataextensionrowcount/#DataExtensionRowCount) on that DE.  E.g.

1. Build a filter based on your initial DE
2. Build a filter activity using your new filter
3. Put the filter into a scheduled automation and run at specified interval (hourly?)
4. Do a DataExtensionRowCount() function to gather the rows in your email and display as output

Sample of DataExtensionRowCount():

```
%%[
SET @DE = 'yourFilteredDE'
SET @rowCount = DataExtensionRowCount(@DE)
]%%
```

Output:

```
%%=v(@rowCount)=%%
```

Comment: Thanks  Gortonington. Is it possible to use SQL query to do the same? How the sql query will look like to pull record count from a data extension? I have used queries on data views but not sure how to use query to pull information from a data extension. can you please help?

Comment: sure, it works identically, you just reference the DE by name. (https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/#section_8)  You can likely get it by something like: `SELECT * FROM yourDE WHERE Status = 'true'`

Answer (score 0):

[**LookupOrderRows()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm) returns a max 2000 rows, per [**the documentation**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuporderedrows.htm).

> Number of rows to return. A value less than 1 returns the default 2000 rows. This limitation enhances script performance.

Here's a full lookup example:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @lookupValue, @i

set @lookupValue = "whee"
set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("DataExtensionName",@numRowsToReturn,"DEColumn1 desc, DEColumn2 asc","LookupColumn", @lookupValue)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

 var @DEColumn1, @DEColumn2
 set @row = row(@rows,@i) /*get row based on loop counter */
 set @DEColumn1 = field(@row,"DEColumn1")
 set @DEColumn2 = field(@row,"DEColumn2")

]%%

 Row %%=v(@i)=%%, DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%, DEColumn2 is %%=v(@DEColumn2)=%%

%%[

next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No rows found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Comment: Hi, I did look into your site as well. All I want to a simple count of rows where column Status is true. The count is more than 500k. Yes, I am aware of the 2000 limitation but I though when we mention tha row count in LookupOrderedRows, we can go more than 2000. no?

Comment: I mean, the ampscript is working fine on my microsite and returning 500,000+ count number. Is there any way to make it work on email?

Comment: What's the use-case for iterating through 500k+ rows in an email?

Comment: The use-case is that I want to know once a week how many records in the data extensions have column "Status" as true. I want the data in an email so that I don;t have to login to the marketing system. My plan was to create email, add amscript and then setup an automation.

Comment: you can go over 2000 limitation in lookuporderedrows, but at great cost to speed and performance. @l-k you would be better off using a rowcount or using SSJS than trying to use LookupOrderedRows().

Comment: @Gortonington  can you please show me an example based on my use-case and amscript above? Just so I understand what you mean by that...

Comment: @l-k see my previously posted answer